# NHibernate LINQ : Why is a query using the incorrect char value if I repeat the call?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Using NHibernate 3.3.1.4000 / .Net 3.5

I have an object I'm mapping to an existing Oracle 10g database :

```
public MyJob : LegacyOracleDbObjects {
    public virtual int JobID { get; protected set; }
    public virtual char Status { get; protected set; }
}
```

And a mapping :

```
public MyJobMap()
{
    Table("JOB");
    Id(x => x.JobID).Column("JOB_ID");
    Map(x => x.Status).Column("STATUS");
}
```

And a LINQ query :

```
char selected_status = 'W'

query = from job in query
        where job.Status == selected_status
        select job;
```

Which works fine the first time I run it, but if I then try to run the query :

```
char selected_status = 'S'

query = from job in query
        where job.Status == selected_status
        select job;
```

NHibernate still passes the value 'W' (i.e. the first value for status) into the database query. I've checked the selected_status value passed into the query, and it looks fine, but the SQL query always contains the original value for selected_status, unless I add a filter for ID, in which case it then uses that status for all subsequent requests regardless of what I pass in.

Any idea why this char query parameter is behaving like this?

Comment: I believe it's a bug, but it might have been fixed in later releases. Please try upgrading to 3.3.3

Comment: This is unresolved as of 4.0.0.4

Comment: By the way, this worked as expected for me when I used HQL instead of LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in NHibernate. There are a few bug entries in the NHibernate issue tracker for it, e.g.: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2500